Is Hashem not obligated to provide for our needs, especially if we have been good?
Since Hashem created mankind, is he not obligated to provide for our needs? Parents are obligated to provide for the needs of their children, should we expect any different from Hashem, especially if we have been ritious and pious? Well, not according to Tehillim 16:2 which says;
"You should say to the Lord,'You are my Master; my good is not incumbent upon You.
Rashi explains: "The benefits that You do for me is not incumbent upon You to bestow [them] upon me, because You do not benefit me on account of my righteousness.
Can someone please help me understand why this is so?

Please bring a source that Hashem is "obligated" to do anything

Describing HaShem as having obligations is either a category error or a figurative anthropomorphism. Any discussion of this question can only begin with this recognition.

The position that says "yes" is from Chazon Ish. It is described in Emuna uBitachon and also in sefer Bitachon vHishtadlus by R'Weinroth (with discenting opinions).

There is a Tosfos in Berachos (I cannot currently find it), that says מאן דיהיב חיה יהיב מזונה meaning The One who gives life gives food. This is according to the attribute of Justice says Tosfos. Hence we say "נברך אלקנו" thanking Hashem (specifically using the name of Hashem that reflects Justice).
However on the other side the Ramban says in Torah Temimah (100) - I believe he states it in Chumash as well - that Hashem is not obligated to reward us - that is why Avraham trusting Hashem for the reward in this world is not an obvious requirement, because Hashem doesn't need to.
I think there is a simple resolution:
When it comes to your personal actions Hashem is not obligated, but because he had created you there should be enough food. Of course there are many functions of this world, and one of them might be to distribute food equitably - like charity. Therefore, yes Hashem makes the world have enough food - but we have a responsibility to help. Only in the wilderness that Hashem specifically led us, was Hashem possibly obligated to help us directly. (See Rav Nechemya Kornitzer on Yisro - that is why Rashi mentions the miracles Elokim (attribute of Justice) did for us is Mana, the well, and saving us from war).

'Rambam says in Torah Temimah (100)' - typo?

Yes. Sorry autocorrected from Ramban

1: He created the concept of obligation. It’s His decision whether or not that concept should apply to Him.
2: We have a concept that one’s main reward is in the World to Come. Material benefits do not perfectly correlate to one’s merits. Anything that one receives in this world is only meant as a tool to increase the amount of goodness he can generate, and the ideal tools vary from person to person.
